# Call a function and Dispatch an action with Redux Thunk inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I've got two functions:
One call the second function and dispatch an action:

```
export function fetchAppClasses() {
  return function (dispatch) {    
    return axios.get(config.apiUrl + '/sdwan/appClasses', axcfg)
      .then(function (response) {
        updateAfterInitialFetch(response);
        dispatch(fetchAppClassesSuccess(response));
      })
  }
}
```

The second function called in the above function:

```
export function updateSelectionAppClassIds(appClasses) {
   // do some stuff
}
```

But when I do this (call a function and dispatch an action) the browser gives me this error:

> ERROR: ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined

If I remove the function updateSelectionAppClassIds call from the fist function and just let the dispatch is does not gives me that error.

How can I call any function and dispatch and action in the same function with Thunk?

This is my configure store:

```
import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const middlewares = [
    // Add other middleware on this line...
    reduxImmutableStateInvariant(),
    thunk  
  ];

  return createStore(rootReducer, initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)    
  );
}
```

I can't do nothing but dispatch in a thunk function, if I do anything else gives me an error.

Comment: post your `configureStore` code, seems like you're not setting up the middleware correctly because your thunk is set up correctly

Comment: do you use `dispatch` in `updateSelectionAppClassIds`?

Comment: Yes, I'am. Has another dispatch.